# Return array from method - java

Tags: java, arrays

```
private static Coordinate[] getCircleCoordintaes() {  
  Coordinate coordinates[] = {new Coordinate(0, 0)};
  return coordinates;   
}
```

Above program working fine. In the above program for return the coordinate array first initialized the array 
using this line

```
Coordinate coordinates[] = {new Coordinate(0, 0)};
```

and then return coordinates.

But when I try to return directly below line then got exception.

```
{new Coordinate(0, 0)}
```

Actually I am trying to find a way to return coordinate array directly. I want to skip the assigning step. May be I am doing something wrong.

How to return this array directly? Any suggestion?

Comment: `return new Coordinate[] {new Coordinate(0, 0)};`? If you want help resolving the exception then you need to tell us exactly what the exception was...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
return new Coordinate[] { new Coordinate(0, 0) }
```

---

To elaborate, the construct you are using (`{new Coordinate(0, 0)};`) is called [*Array initilizer*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6) and as per JLS can be used only in declaration or as part of [*Array creation expression*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10).

> An array initializer may be specified in a declaration (§8.3, §9.3,
>   §14.4), or as part of an array creation expression (§15.10), to create
>   an array and provide some initial values.
>
> ```
> ArrayInitializer:
>     { VariableInitializersopt ,opt }
> ```

Comment: why return new Coordinate[] { new Coordinate(0, 0) } ? you are creating uncessary object, we can achevie this by return new Coordinate[]{0, 0};

Comment: @Ankushsoni You are creating and returning array of Coordinate objects in your example (assume that it is object holding x and y) properties. But this `new Coordinate[]{0, 0}` attempts to create Coordinate array and assign it two int values (0). Therefore this piece of code will not compile.